# How to insert Link of URL with some special Characters in emailto:body?

Tags: javascript, html, email-templates

I am trying to achieve Sending a URL Link in EmailTo:body but having problems.

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=I’d like to share this page with you&amp;body=Check out this interesting information from ABCD Corporation: http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fResources%2fBlog%2fTest-Blog-2%2fOctober%2fLet’s-Abolish-Paper.aspx" title="Share this">Email</a>
```

---

But This Displays following body in outlook (the Special character breaks the link):

[image: This is how it displayed]

But if the body could be generated as given below can work in my favour:

[image: This is How it should displayed]

I tried many things but couldn't succeed.

Thanks

Comment: How are you encoding the URL?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this problem yesterday. Here is my solution and it works perfectly.

What happen here exactly is when we encoding the url encoding is happening fine, but we load on html page or outlook encoded url get decoded because of many factor like iis or some of browser behavior. What I did is I am double encoding. So when page load on outlook it is decode only once, one layer of encoding is still there and we got what we want.

As per you code :

```
var concatID = '&'+"Resource"'&'+"Blog"'&'+"Test-Blog-2"'&'+"October"'&'+"Lets-Abolish-Paper.Aspx";
var enocdedUrlAttr = encodeURIComponent(concatID);
var doubleEnCode = encodeURIComponent(enocdedUrlAttr);
```

Now when you see this in browser you will get desire result. Attach your `doubleEnCode` with your localhost and make url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can still encode a straight quote mark into the email.

`<a href="mailto:?subject=I’d like to share this page with you&amp;body=Check out this interesting information from ABCD Corporation:%0D%0A%0D%0Ahttp%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fResources%2fBlog%2fTest-Blog-2%2fOctober%2fLet%27s-Abolish-Paper.aspx" title="Share this">Email</a>`

[Fiddle of Email Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3SURP/)

Comment: Thanks CJDriver, But This Redirects to 404 page not found, Actually, I need that special quote in the URL, If I manually Edit the link in Outlook & make that like given in 2nd screen shot works correctly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. My example will show a 404 since it's trying to link to a localhost file. Is it showing a 404 when you move it to your code? The special quote doesn't go anywhere, it's just being encoded.

Answer (score -2):

To add a line break you need to use `%0D%0A` where you would like a break (or two).  As your link contains a quote character - which aren't permitted in URLs - will break the link formatting.